# modifying the default github pages layout

Tags: github-pages

I enabled GitHub pages for my repo and overall was quite content with the setup and design. However, I was hoping to change the header slightly which by default is a link to the root of the repo.

It appears that in order to do this I need to create a `default.html` file in a `_layouts`. I went ahead and did this but now it all of the nice defaults that GitHub had are gone. Is it possible to copy/clone whatever defaults are being used and then modify those? In other words, is there a set of files that will replicate the defaults that I can work off of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reaching out to GitHub support I found out that GitHub is actually using a Jeykll theme, and not some custom code! From what I can tell it is the only GitHub provided theme that is not available (currently) in its theme selection page. Apparently someone decided you didn't need to be able to select the default!

The theme's name is "Primer"

https://github.com/pages-themes/primer

With usage info at:

https://github.com/pages-themes/primer#usage